# Any way to get the return value of last method in cascade?

Tags: dart, method-cascades

I'm doing something like this:

```dart
new A()
  ..methodA()
  ..methodB()
  .toString();
```

Should this return the result of `toString()`? Currently it's returning the new `A` object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your code `toString()` is applied on the result of `methodB()`. It's like you are doing :

```dart
var func = (o) {
  o.methodA();
  o.methodB().toString();
  return o;
};
func(new A());
```

To do what you want, you have to do something like :

```dart
(new A()
  ..methodA()
  ..methodB()).toString();
```